# Replace parent view from child route

Tags: ember.js

Following my question here [Nested routes in Ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737960/nested-routes-in-ember) I would like to replace the view rendered from `/settings/users/` with the view rendered by `/settings/users/1`.

My routes are defined as:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('login');
    this.resource('settings', { path: 'settings/:settings_id' }, function() {
        this.route('overview');
        this.route('users', function() {
            this.route('user', { path: ':user_id' });
        });
    });
});
```

My `user.hbs` template will render when `users.hbs` contains `{{outlet}}`. I want the `user.hbs` to render in place of `users.hbs` not within it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your `users` template to just an outlet

```
{{outlet}}
```

And put the stuff from your users template into your `users/index` template, then it will only show up when you're on the `users` route, and when you go any deeper, it won't show the index route.

```
Cool stuff in the users index template
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jacebeyira/1/edit?html,js,output