# How do I change or replace the parent template when rendering a child resource in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have two resources, both of which have a template, model, and controller. The parent resource also has a route. The resources are related to each other in an Ember Data `hasMany` relationship. I've built these in a very straight-forward manner using Ember-Cli

Since you reach the second resource through the first (it has a parent-child relationship), I would like the URL of the parent to look like:

```
/parent/:parent_id
```

And I'd like the URL of the child to look like:

```
/parent/:parent_id/child/:child_id
```

When I try to nest the routes (changing the route and changing the `link-to` helper), and when I display the child route, it renders the child's template right below the parent's template instead of replacing it. I'd like to modify the parent or replace it instead.

Here's a codepen mockup of what's currently outputting for me:

- [Child is not replacing parent](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPNaWx)

I'd like to figure out two things:

**1) Is it possible to make the child resource maintain that URL, but *replace* the parent resource's view (and possibly still have access to both resources models)? How do I do this?**

**2) Is it possible to keep this relationship/view, but cause the parent template to reduce its view when it is viewed in the context of the child URL? Some details of the parent, but fewer. How do I do this?**

## Code

[Output I have working now for `parent/:parent_id/child/:child_id`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPNaWx) (not ideal output! same as codepen above):

```
<div class="row">
  <h1>Parent name</h1>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Parent details 1</p>
      <p>Parent details 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="columns">
    <h3>Child list here</h3>
    <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-4">
      <li><div class="panel">Child 1</div></li>
      <li><div class="panel">Child 2</div></li>
      <li><div class="panel">Child 3</div></li>
      <li><div class="panel">Child 4</div></li>
      <li><div class="panel">Child 1</div></li>
      <li><div class="panel">Child 2</div></li>
      <li><div class="panel">Child 3</div></li>
      <li><div class="panel">Child 4</div></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <h1>Child name</h1>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Child details 1</p>
      <p>Child details 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Output of `parent/:parent_id/child/:child_id` if question 1 is answered](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgrxNx) (much better, and my original intention, to *only* show the child details):

```
<div class="row">
  <h1>Child name</h1>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Child details 1</p>
      <p>Child details 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Output of `parent/:parent_id/child/:child_id` if question 2 is answered](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LExdbW) (I decided while struggling with these nested outputs that this is the ideal output, since it shows the child, but still has a little context and better navigation):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <span><strong>From parent:</strong> Parent name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <a href="/parent/543/child/227">Previous child</a>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <a href="/parent/543/child/229" class="right">Next child</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <h1>Child name</h1>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Child details 1</p>
      <p>Child details 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Part of this is addressed here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738130/replace-parent-view-from-child-route/27738219#27738219 .  Also you can still access a parent route's model from the route using `this.modelFor('foo')` or from a controller using `needs`. (`this.controllerFor('foo')` is also usable in the route, but only after the parent's controller has been setup).

Comment: @Kingpin2k If you'd care to write up an answer, your link helped me figure it out. I think I might end up with non-nested routes because I think I may have figured out how to get `{{#link-to}}` working for multiple dynamic segments, thanks to playing around with manual model retrieval in my router. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEgjrq

Comment: Also, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYPdvw - This demonstrates the behavior you suggested, where you eliminate template layout nesting by using the `*.index` routes of parent resources, and not implementing the non-index version of the routes.